# How expected works in putItemRequest in dynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

As per the documentation of `PutItemRequest`, if we provide the expected map, it is Anded for the provided conditions.

I added following piece of code:

```
Map<String, ExpectedAttributeValue> expected = new HashMap<String, ExpectedAttributeValue>();
            expected.put("userId", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false));
            expected.put("email", new ExpectedAttributeValue(false));
```

Here `userId` is the primary key. This is, however, accepting duplicate email information.

Can anyone please help me in finding what wrong is being done here?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the SDK version you are using? It would be helpful to see an example I could reproduce locally.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate email information.  Duplicates in the one item's `email` attribute, or duplicate emails in the table where users are supposed to have unique emails?

Comment: Assuming that you don't want to have the email address as the unique primary key, you may have to create a GSI on email and then do a lookup to test for duplicates prior to your put. Don't believe that secondary indexes can enforce uniqueness.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand what you are saying now.  If I understand you correctly, you are putting multiple `userId` into a table with an attribute named `email`. You will only get uniqueness on the `hash`+`range` key. The `email` cannot be guaranteed to be unique across the table in this case.

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct. But only issue is if i make user+email as hash+range, i won't be able to guarantee the uniqueness of userId.
I didn't test secondary index. But that is going to take extra throughput, so i wanted to avoid that. 
Only option which seems to be remaining is query before you actually insert. But this option seems quite expensive in terms of latency.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the "email" attribute the range key of your table, then uniqueness is preserved on the combination of hash key=userId and range key=email.

Comment: That way,definitely the combination of (userId, email) will be unique. But i want even the userId to be unique. So that i won't be able to achieve by making email as range